# Create word cloud (word mosaic) programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I'm writing an ios app that can create a word cloud or word mosaic with a pattern selected by user. My question is, how can I calculate the coordinates of each word, considering the sizes of each word is randomly calculated? Or any other approach?

[image: sample]

Note that the pattern I want to work on is like this

[image: face]

but, rather like that, my app will fill the white areas with word mosaic, while preserving the photo of the user.

[EDIT]
my algorithm right now is to randomly set the size and position of each words and just put them there. How can I check if each word that I'm putting doesn't intersect with each other and the photo?

Reference: http://www.imagechef.com/ic/word_mosaic/