# Create a word cloud on selected pixels

Tags: php

I am trying to create a word cloud of a person's face. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847906/create-word-cloud-word-mosaic-programmatically)

To achieve this I got a black & white image of a person and turned the darkest pixel to black and lightest pixel to white. And here is my result

[image]

Now I have got the area where I would like to place word clouds. Now I can't figure out how do I place words inside the face keeping margin/angle between words.

Here's the code what i have done so far

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$src = 'person.jpeg';

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$size = getimagesize($src);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

$white_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

$font = __DIR__ . "/testfont.ttf";
$font_size = 16;
$text = "Test text";

$skip = true;
for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;


        if ($r >= 126) {
            imagesetpixel($image_p, $x, $y, $white_color);
        } else {
            imagesetpixel($image_p, $x, $y, $black_color);

            if ($x % 20 == 1) {
                imagestring($image_p, 5, $x, $y, 'T', $black_color);
                //imagettftext($image_p, 16, 0, $x, $y, $black_color, $font, $text);
            }
        }
        //var_dump($r, $g, $b);
        //echo "<br/>";
    }
}
imagestring($image_p, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $black_color);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

I tried using `imagestring` & `imagettftext`

```
if ($x % 20 == 1) {
                imagestring($image_p, 5, $x, $y, 'T', $black_color);
                //imagettftext($image_p, 16, 0, $x, $y, $black_color, $font, $text);
            }
```

And got weird output. With `imagettftext` it takes too long to render and with `imagestring` this is what I got

[image]

Comment: You are sampling every single pixel in the image so ofcourse it's going to take a lot of time, where do you want to write exactly? or what are you trying to accomplish? Personally when I had to work with images I had an easier time using imagine library than using these functions directly & JFYI Imagick would be faster so i'd go with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of these functions not both of them: imagesetpixel or imagestring
And if you have B/W photo, forget $black_color & $white_color or add them to this codes to customize more. And also add your custom header in the end.

```
list($w, $h, $type) = getimagesize('person.jpeg');
$resource = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('person.jpeg'));
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
for($y=0; $y<$h; $y+=20)
    for($x=0; $x<$w; $x+=20)
        imagestring($img, 5, $x, $y, 'Hello world!', imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me.  I create a png image template in the Gimp, save it.  Trickiest part for me was figuring out the font path aspect, since the font file just had to be in the one directory.

```
<?php
    // Create Image From Existing File
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('baseimg.png');
    // Allocate A Color For The Text
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 125, 125, 255);
    // Set Path to Font File
    $font_path = './FreeSans.ttf';
    $text = "Hello World!";

    // Print Text On Image
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 15, 110, $black, $font_path, $text);

    //Set the Content Type
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    // Send Image to Browser
    imagepng($image);

    // Clear Memory
    imagedestroy($image);

    exit;
?>
```